# Eclipse: Unfortunately, App name (helloandroid1) has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm new in eclipse I have a assignment for my first android app, my problem is when I clicked the "Time Table" item, a error(Unfortunately, helloandroid1 has stopped.) is pop up. but the other items are working well.

**Codes:**

- LogCat:  [my logcat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgK95.jpg)
- Manifest.xml

  ```
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity
  android:name="menu"
  android:label="@string/menu">

  </activity>


  <activity 
      android:name=".contacts"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      </activity>
  <activity 
      android:name="com.example.helloandroid1.time_table"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      </activity>
  ```
- Menu.java:

  ```
  package com.example.helloandroid1;
  import com.example.helloandroid1.R;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.widget.*;


  public class menu extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.menu);

      ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_menu);

      String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);
      menuList.setAdapter(adapt);

      menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      ((TextView) itemClicked).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                      .show();

              TextView textview = (TextView) itemClicked;
              String strText = textview.getText().toString();
              switch(position){
              case 0:
                  //When clicked, show a toast  with the TextView text
                  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                  //break;
                  startActivity(new Intent(menu.this,contacts.class));
                  break;

              case 1:
                  //When clicked, show a toast  with the TextView text
                  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //break;
                  startActivity(new Intent(menu.this,time_table.class));
                  break;

              case 2:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Description.html")));
                  break;
              case 3:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Syllabus.html")));
                  break;
              case 4:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Lectures.html")));
                  break;
              case 5:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Labs.html")));
                  break;
              case 6:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Exams.html")));
                  break;
              case 7:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Project.html")));
                  break;
              case 8:
                  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Links.html")));
                  break;  

                      default:
                              //When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              break;
              }

          }
      });

      }



  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome_screen, menu);
      return true;
  }
  }
  ```

My menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/ustblue" >



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView_menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) itemClicked).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();

TextView textview = (TextView) itemClicked;
String strText = textview.getText().toString();
```

to

```
String strText = menuList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: should I change the Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), to String strText = textview.getText().toString(); 

or just the "String strText = textview.getText().toString();" 
with the 
"String strText = menuList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();"?

Answer (score 0):

Null value is passing from that menu list ,better you add validation for size of that menu list ,that will solve your problem.If you explain what you are passing in menu list i will explain and assist you even better.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class menu extends Activity {

    private ListView menuList;
    private String[] items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_menu);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);

        adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);
        menuList.setAdapter(adapt);

        menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText(menu.this,items[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String strText = items[position];
                switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(menu.this,contacts.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(menu.this,time_table.class));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Description.html")));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Syllabus.html")));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Lectures.html")));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Labs.html")));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Exams.html")));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Project.html")));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://course.cse.ust.hk/comp4521/Links.html")));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```